# How to use std::istream instead of file with libzip?

Tags: c++, stream, zip, libzip

I have code like this:

```
#include <libzip/zip.h>

void main()
{
    int err;
    struct zip* zip_file = zip_open("some_file.zip", 0, &err);

    struct zip_file* file_in_zip = zip_fopen_index(zip_file_, 0, 0);

    char buff[1024];
    std::ofstream exctracted("extracted_data");
    while((readed = zip_fread(file_in_zip, buff, 1024)) > 0)
    {
         exctracted.write(buff, readed);
    }

    zip_close(zip_file);
}
```

And what if I have not file on filesystem (like `some_file.zip`), but only `std::istream` instead? How to get `struct zip*` object without saving stream to filesystem?
I see to the [documentation](https://libzip.org/documentation/) of libzip, but can`t find out how to do that.

Comment: Zip can't do seek on a stream

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with libzip, but after reviewing the documentation I don't think there is a way you can accomplish what you seek. When faced with similar circumstances in the past (zipping to memory and back vs a file and back) I've resorted to using zlib and their minizip contrib, with custom source objects to perform in-memory ops rather than the default filesys ops. If libzip can do this too, great (because you can wire it to any source/sink you want. I couldn't find it but your luck may fare better). If not, you may have to resort to a different toolkit.